# Add authentication roles orangeHRM

Tags: symfony-1.4, orangehrm

I have added a new authentication roles for orangeHRM , it must access all menu and sub menu except Salary, i have added same roles which admin has to following tables.

```
ohrm_user_role_data_group
ohrm_user_role_screen 
ohrm_data_group_screen
```

but it not coming as ordered like menu and sub menu, all are coming as menu only.

Answer (score 0):

In `ohrm_menu` (Table which has the menu information) where you have to set the level of a menu item and the parent of a current menu item. So you can have your sub menus organized under a top menu item. See that helps!